# Backbone and slim framework redirect route htacces

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, backbone.js, slim

I'm trying to configure htaccess for my backbone and slim Webapp.

Here is my root url:  `mysite.com/myproject/`

Here is how I'm organizing my directories:

[image: directories]

- `server.php`, where I use Slim framework, and define my 'routes'
- one directory that contains Slim framework called `data`
- one directory that contains my Backbone app called `js`

I would like do something like `mysite.com/myproject/post`s to get full list of my posts
or `mysite.com/myproject/post/:id` to get one post

I know that I can use redirect to "simulate" URLs that do not exist.
In theory if I try `mysite.com/posts`, Apache/`.htaccess` redirect to `server.php` where my "routes" do what I want and return my result to backbone.

But whatever I've tried, does seem to work.

**EDIT**

I've find part of solution.

I moved htaccess and server.php files into data directorie.

Here is my server.php file

```
<?php
    require_once("Slim/Slim.php");
    $app = new Slim();

    $app->get('/posts','getPosts');
    $app->get('/post/:id','getPost');

    $app->run();

    function getPosts() { echo "Hello world, get post list"; }
    function getPost($id) { echo "Hello world, get one post = ".$id; }
?>
```

Here is my backbone collection declaration

```
window.PostList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Post,
        url:"data/posts",

        initialize : function() {
            console.log ("collection created.")
        }
    });
```

And .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/data
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ server.php [QSA,L]
```

On `fetch method` of backbone, request was sent to `http://mysite.com/myproject/data/posts`
and i can see response into console `Hello world, get post list`

but i can't do request like `mysite/myproject/posts`
which value for `RewriteBase` ? which value for `backbone collection` ?

Comment: Typically you would configure a `VirtualHost` directive in Apache, but virtual host configuration can not be defined in `.htaccess`. Do you have access to modify the server configuration (`httpd.conf`)? See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: thk for reply but no i can't access to httpd.conf.i'm try this cause i'm following this answer http://bit.ly/qVSQgx on stackoverflow

Comment: And i'm using this tutorial http://bit.ly/Zdb3Iv and replace jquery ajax calls by CRUD methods of backbone.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you need to do is create a [rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) for `mysite.com/posts` instead of a 301 or 302 redirect.

So you'd have your server rewrite `mysite.com/posts` to server.php.  This way `/posts` is still the URL.

Then you'd initialize your Backbone router to start and know how to handle `/posts`

```
var my_router = new (Backbone.Router.extend())();
my_router.route('/path/:id', show_post);
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/});
```

Or something similar.

The trick being that the URL in your browser needs to match what Backbone is being told the route is. After that routes will no longer be called from your server, but you should support them if they have to reload or come in from scratch.

The best way to handle this is to actually make your rewrite rule something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/posts/(.*?)    server.php?post=$1 [L,R]
```

(Or something depending on how your `server.php` script works and how you want your URL structure to work).

Comment: i'll try this asap.

in backbone if i set my route like this '/myproject/server.php/post' it work like a charm.

but i think it's dirty to do that like that. that's why i would replace '/myproject/server.php/post' by '/myproject/post'